# Retrain im2txt model with Open Images dataset

Tags: tensorflow

I have a trained *im2txt* model (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/im2txt). I used MSCOCO imageset for the training as it was written in the docs.

I want to continue training with Google Open Images Dataset.

I'm wondering if it is possible to retrain im2txt model and what I need to do to prepare a new dataset for the training. It seems that Google dataset and MSCOCO dataset have different formats.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Open Images Dataset link: https://research.googleblog.com/2016/09/introducing-open-images-dataset.html.

Comment: Microsoft COCO dataset link http://mscoco.org/dataset/#download

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it might be possible to retrain the model, remember that these two data sets come with different labeling semantics and conventions, so understand that the results might not be 100% comparable.

You need to pre-process the data using a script similar to the [COCO script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/e5cae33030244bcdff78df3139f36f0af07f4d6a/im2txt/im2txt/data/build_mscoco_data.py).

There is a [script](https://github.com/openimages/dataset/blob/master/tools/classify.py#L89) provided for inference in the openimages distribution, but it does contain code to unpack the data.

Finally, if you get this done, we're always open to contributions in the form of pull requests at our [github models](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/models) page.

Comment: Thanks, drpng, I will try to do this way.